# Question on nature of solutions of a first order ordinary differential equation..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to know that a given first order ordinary differential equation has a unique solution, no solution, finite number of solutions or an infinitely many solutions ?

Comment: There are a number of theorems used to prove existence and uniqueness. For example, the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem).

Comment: Are you including n your question initial or boundary conditions?

Comment: For initial value problem only